# The Stack Exchange iOS app should allow for certain types of notifications to be turned off, or implement 'do not disturb'

Tags: discussion, feature-request, ios-app

Before the MSO/SE split, I'd never gotten notifications when someone posted a new meta question to meta.stackoverflow.com (thank God, right?).  Now that the split has occurred, I've gotten at least 1 notification when a new question was added to meta.stackoverflow.com.

Two possible feature requests stemming from the same issue:

> I don't want to get a notification every time a question is asked on the largest Meta Stack Exchange that exists.

There are two ways I see of handling it:

1. Implement a 'do not disturb' function, so that I don't get iOS notifications during a certain time period (10am-6am, for instance).
2. Implement the ability to turn on and off certain types of notifications.

I use the Stack Exchange app as a moderator because it provides me with the ability to communicate instantly when an issue of moderation arises. If it's going to notify me for every Meta post, it's not going to be useful to me anymore.

Comment: Wait, I thought *this* meta was the biggest.. ;P

Comment: Definitely option 2. Option 1 would feel redundant given the built in do not disturb scheduling in iOS